# Excel VBA: How to search and copy a value of a certain pattern found within large texts in a column to another column?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

As shown in the image above, I need to get the values following a pattern like for example TK AK15590 (TK AK followed by a series of numbers as shown) into cell B2. The same with the rest of the cells in the description column using vba macro in excel. Appreciate if anyone could give me a sample vba code or some information on how I could do this.

Comment: Depending on the variability in your data, you could probably either use the `Like` operator, or, if things are too complicated for that, `Regular Expressions`.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we would be glad to help you out with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA is not requiered here. You should use formulas that manipulate text. In this particular case, the following would work:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("TK AK",A2),FIND(" ",A2,FIND("TK AK",A2)+4)-FIND("TK AK",A2)), "ERROR MESSAGE HERE")
```

When the length of the string you want to extract is fixed (10 in this case), you could simply use this:

```
 =IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("TK AK",A2),10), "ERROR MESSAGE HERE")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help